# Java (Swing): finding a component's *screen* size when the window is resized

Tags: java, swing, resize

I need to find a component's exact screen size in pixels when the main JFrame is resized.

I've tried several things and couldn't find an easy way to do it: it probably have missed something obvious.

```
BBBBB JFRAME BORDER BBB
BZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZB
BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB
BCC1................DDB
BCCC................DDB
BCCC................DDB
BCCC................DDB
BCCC................2DB
BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Resized, it could become this if, say, the user made the main JFrame shorter (vertically) and wider (horizontally):

```
 BBBBBB JFRAME BORDER BBBBBB
 BZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZB
 BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB
 BCC1....................DDB
 BCCC....................2DB
 BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEB
 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

What I want is to find the exact size in pixels, on screen, of the rectangle area indicated by dots.

I'm adding a `ComponentListener` to get the resizing events, which works fine.

The issue I'm having is that calling getWidth()/getHeight() on a Component does apparently **not** return the component's screen size but the component's actual size (and you can have, for example, a JPanel wider than the component it is into).

Any hint most welcome.

Comment: +1 for the ASCII art drawings.

Comment: @Finglas: thanks, figured out it was more "resilient" than some Photobucket image link or such :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [JComponent.getVisibleRect()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getVisibleRect%28%29).

Comment: thanks a lot, I *knew* I was missing something obvious.  Solves my problem nicely and works fine with the layout manager I'm using etc.   :)

Answer (score 1):

`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` returns the width and height of the component. I've never heard of any difference between "actual" width/height and "screen" width/height.

Some layout managers however, does not fill the panel with a component it contains, and some space between the component and the panels edge may not be occupied by the component. In that case I usually `setBackground(Color.BLUE)` on the underlying panel to see what's going on.

Comment: @aioobe: you've never seen a JPanel who's content is cropped because the JFrame is smaller than the JPanel !?

Comment: If that's the behavior you see, then it seems like your layout-manager is broken. Which layout manager are you using?

Comment: @aioobe: IntelliJ IDEA's GridLayoutManager which is probably used for IntelliJ IDEA itself.  I somehow have doubt it is broken but I'll try with a BorderLayout to see.

Comment: @aioobe: can you explain me what happens when you put a component that has a minimum width of, say, 100, in a JFrame that is 50 pixels wide.  What is a non-broken layout-manager supposed to do here?

Comment: Well take GridLayout for instance, it will not respect the minimum size. I believe minimum/maximum/preferred size are seen as "hints" for the layout manager. Can't find a reference for it though.

Comment: From [Suns Java Tutorial on layout managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html)

> If the component is not controlled by a layout manager, you can set its size by invoking the setSize or setBounds  method on it. Otherwise, you need to provide size hints and then make sure you are using a layout manager that respects the size hints.

Comment: @aiooble: oh I see...  Still haven't fixed my issue but thanks a lot for the links and explanation, good read :)

Comment: Okey, @Nate just provided the solution for you! I had no idea about that method!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very rubbish way but you can use a wrapper Panel, where you put your main panel into. Than you can call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` from the wrapper panel.

Comment: he he, I tried that too but in my case it didn't work: I still would have component(s) giving me a getWidth()/getHeight() that would *not* be the real w/h.  However Nate's answer is right on spot: *getVisibleRect()* does **really** give back the real visible rect :)